# Почему Pandas Series rolling конвертирует int во float?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, cython

Коллеги, столкнулся с непонятным поведением метода `pandas.series.rolling` прошу пояснить. Для исследования возьмем вот такой искусственный код:

```
import pandas as pd


def rolling_print(x):
    print(x)
    return float('nan')


ser = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
print(ser)
ser.rolling(5).apply(rolling_print)
```

Поясню: берем `pandas.series` из `int` от 1 до 9, применяем к этой серии метод `rolling` с окном 5 (неважно какое значение окна, я пробовал и с `int` и с `datetime`), и затем с помощью `apply` вызываем функцию, для того, чтобы выводить данные из каждого окна. Так вот, при выводе становится видно, что данные превратились из `int` во `float`. То есть `1.0, 2.0...` и т.д. Почему? (Замена возвращаемых данных с `float('nan')` на любую константу типа `int` результат не изменила)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как написано в обсуждении [BUG: Pandas rolling window always converts to float #53214](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/53214)

> The issue here is that our Cython code that handles rolling can only take in float64 inputs, so the input is cast beforehand to float64 here.

> Проблема в том, что наш код на Cython, которые обрабатывает функционал rolling, может принимать только значения типа float64, поэтому входные данные заранее преобразовываются в формат float64.

Таков путь.

Comment: Исчерпывающе. Благодарю!